# Jquery AJAX id selector and post with change class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have one question. I am trying to make a ajax post with id and also trying to change the class which `data-id` selected.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/VLQrQZ)** from *codepen.io*

In this demo you can see there is a two container div and the container divs inside some different color div.

So what i am trying to do. When i click `.change_pri` then that clicked (`.style, style1, style2`) will automatically change `.type` style like:

```
<div class="test" id="1">
  <div class="type style">selected color</div> <-- class is style
  <div class="select_types">
    <div class="type_s"><div class="change_pri style" data-id="0">0</div></div>
    <div class="type_s"><div class="change_pri style1" data-id="1">1</div></div>
    <div class="type_s"><div class="change_pri style2" data-id="2">2</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

after clicking change_pri style2 then it need to looks like this:

```
<div class="test" id="1">
  <div class="type style2">selected color</div> <-- after clicking class is style2
  <div class="select_types">
    <div class="type_s"><div class="change_pri style" data-id="0">0</div></div>
    <div class="type_s"><div class="change_pri style1" data-id="1">1</div></div>
    <div class="type_s"><div class="change_pri style2" data-id="2">2</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and post the data-id with ajax.

I do not know how the rest of that section, but I was able to do so. Anyone can help me in this regard ?

```
$(function() {
  var i;
  i = $(this).attr('id');
});
$('.change_pri').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chage_number.php",
    data: {
      id: i,
    },
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript with the AJAX request should probably look something like this:

```
$('.change_pri').click(function(){
    var dataid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var id = $(this).closest('.test').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "chage_number.php",
        data: { dataid : dataid, id: id }
    }).success(function(result){
        alert(result);
    });
});
```

And then depending on what you want to do back-end, you can access that variable in **chage_number.php** via `$_POST['id']`.

So a simple example would be

**chage_number.php**

```
echo $_POST['id'] . ", ". $_POST['dataid'];
```

This should `alert()` both ids.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the normal id is post id and data-id is selected id like value.

Comment: You wanted to send the data-id? My code works just fine. `.data('id')` works too. @innovation

Comment: @innovation Updated, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..

```
$('.change_pri').on('click', function(e) {
  var styletype = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]; 
  var ctoremove = $('.type').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
  $('.type').removeClass(ctoremove).addClass(styletype);
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "chage_number.php",
        data: { id: i }
    }).success(function(result){
        alert(result);
    });
});
```

and here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vc2xavp9/)

Comment: This not a good solution. Because there is two post `<div class="test" id="1">` and `<div class="test" id="2">`

Comment: where does `i` come from?

Answer (score 0):

I take it as the second container should be an example of what happens clicking the div's of the first one.

See this working example, it should do what you asked for: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdxVzW

This is where you get an alert telling you which data-id you clicked and then it changes the class of the `.type` element

```
alert($(this).attr('data-id')); //this can be removed, it's just a test

$('#test-1 > .type')  //remove styleN and add the needed one
  .removeClass('style0')
  .removeClass('style1')
  .removeClass('style2')
  .addClass('style'+$(this).attr('data-id'))
```

The part about the ajax call remains almost the same, with a little modification when it comes to setting the id to be sent:

```
$('.change_pri').on('click', function(e) {

  //As suggested by @Mackan, a little modification: store data-id
  var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chage_number.php",
    data: {
    id: dataId //send the correct id
    }
  });
});
```

The function at the beginning of the script can be safely removed, it doesn't affect the rest of the code :)

I was almost forgetting: add a `0` to the style which doesn't have a number, like:

```
<div class="change_pri style0" data-id="0">0</div></div>
```

Otherwise when it come's to `data-id=0` the script doesn't know what to do. Of course, same thing should be done into css code:

```
.style0{
  background-color:red;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: I think you're wrong in the `data` option of the Ajax call. `this` will not refer to the clicked element when inside the Ajax call. Also the trailing comma should go.

Comment: And..there you go! You're right, I usually store data before ajax call, don't know why I did it that way :) Thanks for the note!

Comment: @ErenorPaz the number is only example. My CSS code has not number like style0, style1, style2. I am only using style. Numbers to be descriptive. The gustaf code will help me for selector. Now i need to change style. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @innovation Np: The important thing is that you got the help you were searching for :)